# how to find out block and network used by docker container

Tags: monitoring, docker, stats

I have confusion to understand docker container stats for NET I/O and BLOCK I/O. As per official documentation.
NET I/O => The amount of data the container has sent and received over its network interface
BLOCK I/O => The amount of data the container has read to and written from block devices on the host

In my case output is 
NET I/O => 132MB / 273MB
BLOCK I/O => 6.03GB / 7.16GB

I am not understanding whether these values are per second or an average of certain period say each day. Please help me with this. Also, let me know backend files storing this values.

Answer (score 1):

Those statistics values are raw data added as your container is running. If you read NET I/O 132Mb/273Mb that means since the container starts, it has read 132Mb and send 273Mb.

So those values are not per second or average, there are total amount.

To store those values, you can use the *docker stat* command and process the output with "whatever you are confortable with" kind of script (shell tools like cut, akw or python script, etc). The output of your script will depend on what you are doing (kind of CSV, data logger formatter).